# StAX find Corresponding End Tag?

Tags: java, xml, stax

Is it possible / is there an easy way to find an end tag (END_ELEMENT) corresponding to a START_ELEMENT as in the following?

```
while(reader.hasNext()){
        XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();

        if(event.getEventType() == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT){
            StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
            System.out.println(startElement.getName().getLocalPart());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you by the mean the easy way to have a call to return the end element the answer is no. SAX parsers are event based parsers, so it read your XML file and create events. It is up to you to handle these events and build your memory structure as these events come.

Maybe you should use a DOM parser which builds up the XML structure in the memory and you can navigate in it. Or use some xml bindig (e.g JAXB) which translate an XML to java objects and vica-versa.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is:

- to create a `StreamFilter` which has an internal *depth* counter ; its `accept` method will:

  - increment each time there is a `START_ELEMENT` event and decremented each time there is a `END_ELEMENT` event
  - return `true` if and only if the depth is zero
- to read from a `FilterReader` based on this filter for the orignal stream when you encounter your particular start tag:

Then

```
    if(event.getEventType() == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT){
        StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
        System.out.println(startElement.getName().getLocalPart());
        if (/* you want the end of this start tag */) {
          Reader forwardToMatchingEndReader = xmlInputFactory.createFilterReader(reader, filter)
          XMLEvent matchingEndEvent = forwardToMatchingEndReader.next();
        }
    }
```